# Access Dynamics CRM 4 SPLA (IFD) DiscoveryService from CRM 2011 IFD

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

We have just upgraded from Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4 to Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011. Most of the upgrade has gone smoothly, however I have some custom code (written for CRM 4) which uses the CrmDiscoveryService at the URL "https:///MSCRMServices/2007/SPLA/CrmDiscoverService.asmx" which worked fine on our Dynamics CRM 4 server but not with out Dynamics CRM 2011 server.

Our Dynamics CRM 2011 server is set up On Premise, as an IFD deployment. On the actual Dynamics CRM 2011 server box I can navigate to "https://:444/MSCRMServices/2007/SPLA/CrmDiscoveryService.asmx" and I am directed to the correct web service, however if I try to access this from any other computer I get a infinitely looped redirect.

Using Fidler I can read what is being sent when I try to navigate to the CrmDiscoveryService URL and the response, before I am redirected is:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 237
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: https://<server>:444/MSCRMServices/2007/SPLA/CrmDiscoveryService.asmx
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2011 23:31:26 GMT

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https&#58;&#47;&#47;<server>&#58;444&#47;MSCRMServices&#47;2007&#47;SPLA&#47;CrmDiscoveryService.asmx">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

I believe that Dynamics CRM is trying to redirect me to the actual page I have gone to, and thus it is looping into infinity.

I originally had this issue with the Discovery Service: http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/crmdeployment/thread/d92924d8-5982-4a11-ac66-602feb4542c8/?prof=required however I was able to correct this by allowing anonymous authentication to the folder the Discover Service was located in.

After some extensive searches I am yet to find anything on the Discovery Service infinite redirect issue I am now having.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've solved the problem, kind of...

I'll post it here so as anybody else experiencing the same thing will be able to figure it out out (there's nothing worse than seeing an empty thread for a problem that one is having).

It turns out that while I cannot access this URL via Internet Explorer, when used authenticating via IFD in custom code this works correctly.

I'd still be interested though in finding out why it works in my custom code but not Internet Explorer.