# crm 2011 legacy discovery web service

Tags: web-services, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-4, legacy

I've been trying to connect to a CRM 2011 IFD legacy discovery web service but have not been able to do so. I've gone from getting a *401 not authorized* to a *404 not able to connect to site* when attempting to connect with a browser.

When I try to add the web service to it as a web reference in VS 2010, I get an error saying that number of redirects are too many (or something similar).

I've seen people being able to connect to the web service in custom code where they authorize themselves in the code but I'm not sure how do to do that. I can't set up discovery service using the DLLs from the SDK for CRM 2011 without adding the discovery service as a web reference.

Can anyone give me som advice on how to procede with this. I need to be able to reach the legacy service due to a third party product.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8408560/access-dynamics-crm-4-spla-ifd-discoveryservice-from-crm-2011-ifd

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use `crmsvcutil.exe` from the `MS CRM SDK`. It generates proxy class from `WSDL` allowing you to break through IFD and reach the service endpoint.